# How to retrieve "id" and "data" value using Jquery Draggable events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-draggable

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( ".thumblink" ).draggable({
      stop: function( event, ui ) {
          var pos_x = ui.offset.left;
          var pos_y = ui.offset.top;
            console.log($(this).attr('id'));
            console.log($(this).attr('data-need'));
       $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"save.php",
            data:{x:pos_x,y:pos_y}
            });
            
          },
      containment: "parent",
      cursor: 'move'
    });
```

My HTML code;

```
<a href="" class="thumblink"  data-need="12" "id="imglink1"><img src="rest/o.png width='50' height='50' border="0"/></a>


console.log($(this).attr('id')); gives me null value
console.log($(this).attr('data-need')); undefined value
How to retrieve my anchor tag "id" and "data need" value please help.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` object to access the id

`var ancId=$(this).attr('id');
 var dataNeed=$(this).attr('data-need');`

call this inside the stop function of your `draggable` call back function

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Sorry it did not worked, when i console.log it gave me undefined value

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to access the id in your code ? dont add these  lines of code within the ajax module, place it within `$( ".thumblink" ).draggable({
      stop: function( event, ui ) {
           var ancId=$(this).attr('id');
           var dataNeed=$(this).attr('data-need'); }`

Comment: Yes exactly i did the same thing, it gave me id empty and dataneed undefined

Comment: Happy Coding it worked finally Thanks +1 for support, problem with my html code

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke: yeah i too was confused, when you its not working, while working it out jsfiddle, i realized, there were lot of syntax errors. good to know you resolved it. happy coding :)

Comment: FYI my name is dreamweiver , happy coding was just a greeting ;)